# HTML: <p> tag pushes down floating <div>

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a website design (relearning HTML and CSS, as I haven't used them for several years), and I've come across what appears to be a rather simple problem, and one I'm sure I've come across before, but can't remember how to fix.

In my design, I have the main content to the left of the page, and a sidebar to the right: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j7MUS/1/). The sidebar is float: right;, and the content container is float: right;. The problem is, which ever element appears first pushes down the other element. I want them to sit side by side next to each other.

HTML:

```
...
<div id='page-container'>
<aside id='sidebar'>
  <div class='sidebar-item'>
    <p>Sidebar</p>
  </div>
</aside>

<main id='body-container'>
  <h1 id='main-title'>Welcome to WebsiteName!</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent ut erat
    volutpat, semper metus id, suscipit justo. Maecenas ut lacus sit amet lacus
    elementum tempus. Suspendisse sit amet sem venenatis, mollis enim vel,
    vehicula nisi. Phasellus sed condimentum ligula. Curabitur vehicula sem in
    volutpat vulputate. Maecenas feugiat ipsum quis quam euismod lacinia. In
    congue vel dui ac dignissim. Maecenas iaculis, odio fermentum tincidunt
    aliquam, elit massa tristique nisl, quis fringilla nisl purus sed risus.
    Cras malesuada posuere elit sed auctor. Phasellus hendrerit adipiscing
    commodo.</p>
  <img id='image' src='logo.svg' alt='PollardNET | Home' />
</main>

<div class='clearer'>
  <!--Needed to ensure floats work correctly!-->
</div>
</div>
...
```

CSS:

```
...
#sidebar {
  float: right;
  margin: 100px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-left-width: 2px;
  border-left-color: #a4a4a4;
}

#body-container {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px;
  margin-right: 427px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
...
.clearer {
  clear: both;
}
...
```

If I remove any text (p tags) from the content section, the problem seems goes away. For some reason this does not work in jsfiddle, but shows in Chrome. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `float: left;` from your `#body-container`. Generally speaking you don't need to specify two floats for each side, only one float is enough. See [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j7MUS/6/).

Comment: Thanks very much indeed! That has fixed it. Why is this the case? Surely it shouldn't matter if two floats are specified? It seems a bit counter intuitive to me. I'll mark it as accepted once the time limit is up.

Comment: @jdp407 When you float an element, you're removing it from the document flow. So if you float both things inside `#page-container` instead of just one, there's nothing inside `#page-container` anymore except for your clearfix div. Therefore, your browser tries to push both your `#body-container` and `#sidebar` **below** your clearfix, which is obviously not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position: absolute` and set a width for both division.

```
#sidebar {
  ...
  position: absolute;
}

#body-container {
  ...
  position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Put it in span instead of p or use float on p

```
p {
  float:left;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to remove the float, you can also take the margin-right off body-container and give it a width.

Floating an element makes it `display:block`. By default, a block element in HTML will have a full line width. That's why the body-container pushes the sidebar down if it doesn't have a set width or if it doesn't have `display: inline`