# Why is a trailing <br> tag in one floating div able to push down another floating div on my page?

Tags: css, html, css-float

Currently the page is just two divs sitting side by side inside a containing section.  I had two trailing `<br>` tags on qtr_calc, which were pushing down sem_calc.  Shouldn't qtr_calc be able to have as many newlines at the bottom as I like without affecting sem_calc? If not, is there a workaround?

Somebody had a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25108505/html-p-tag-pushes-down-floating-div), but there no explanation of why this is able to occur and the answer that helped them does not help me.

The divs' html:

```
<section id="content">
  <div id="qtr_calc">
     <label for="qtr_cred_hrs">Quarter class credit hours:</label><br />
     <input type="text" id="qtr_cred_hours" /><br /><br />
     <label for="qtr_grade">Letter grade:</label><br />
     <input type="text" id="qtr_grade" /></div>
  </div>
  <div id="sem_calc">
     <label for="sem_cred_hrs">Semester class credit hours:</label><br />
     <input type="text" id="sem_cred_hours" /><br /><br />
     <label for="sem_grade">Letter grade:</label><br />
     <input type="text" id="sem_grade" /></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

The divs' CSS:

```
#qtr_calc { 
   float: left;
   margin: 3em;
   padding: 2em;
   border: 1px double #F2F2F2; /* inside border */
   outline: 1px solid #BFBFBF; /* outside border */
}

#sem_calc {
   float: left;
   top: 0;
   margin: 3em;
   padding: 2em;
   border: 1px double #F2F2F2; /* inside border */
   outline: 1px solid #BFBFBF; /* outside border */
}
```

[And here's a pastebin with the rest of the page, in case it helps somehow.](http://pastebin.com/SWuX90aV)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/22wwh5pg/ if you make the output frame wider, it shows both on the same line

Comment: You seem to have two extra `</div>`s in your markup.

Comment: You closed your divs too early or you got extra closing div tags see http://jsfiddle.net/22wwh5pg/2/ the second block has a red closing div tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra closing div tag here:

```
<input type="text" id="qtr_grade" /></div>
```

**[Demo](http://liveweave.com/5wSONG)**

Comment: Found both extra ending tags, removed them, and it fixed the issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove extra closing Div's and top:0; and try to give them width say 20%. That should solve you problem.